# Two terms for a president

Tags: united-states, constitutional-law, us-constitution, president

If a Vice President becomes President on the death of a President such as with LBJ and the election is not for two years.  Are they allowed to stand for two addition terms or is the rest of the term for which he has become president is classed as the first term?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It depends on the time when the President dies

If the president dies with *exactly or less* than 2 years remaining on his term, the vice president is counted as not having had one term. They can be reelected **twice**.

If the president dies with *more* than 2 years remaining on his term, the vice president is counted as having had one term. They can be reelected **once**.

That's very clear from the [22nd amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-second_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution):

> Section 1. **No person shall be elected to the office of the President more than twice**, and **no person who has held the office of President, or acted as President, for more than two years** of a term to which some other person was elected President **shall be elected to the office of the President more than once.**

Comment: The first paragraph should say "two years or less," not "less than two years."

Comment: @phoog clarified - typically that's 720 days.

Comment: The latter two years of a presidential term is usually 721 days, not 720 (but not always; e.g. not the terms ending in 1801, 1901, 2101, 2201, 2301, 2501, etc ). But it depends on how you count, and you don't know if someone accedes to the presidency at the 2-year mark how the courts will count.  Maybe the cutoff is noon on January 20th; maybe it's midnight.  Would that be the midnight between the 19th and the 20th or between the 20th and the 21st?  Maybe they come up with some other definition of "year."  ...

Comment: ... It's better to refrain from interpreting the law yourself and from being over precise, and just to say "two years or less."  (It reminds me of the tendency to interpret the word "majority" incorrectly by saying 50% + 1, or worse, 51%, instead of just saying "majority.")

Comment: Did this count for Harry Truman the incumbent in 1952 as well?

Comment: @NeilMeyer no, Trueman was specifically excluded by the rest of section one, the Grandfather clause which applies to nobody else and can't:  *But this Article shall not apply to any person holding the office of President when this Article was proposed by the Congress, and shall not prevent any person who may be holding the office of President, or acting as President, **during the term within which this Article becomes operative from holding the office of President or acting as President during the remainder of such term.***